# Generate array from another array by key value

Tags: php, arrays

Hi i have array with have date and view count, i want to get from this view count last 7 days if this have for example

```
$view = array("31.01.2020"=>2,"02.02.2020"=>2,"05.02.2020"=>2,"06.02.2020"=>2);
```

i want to get from this array last 7 day and month if today is 12.02.2020 i will have this array for week

```
$week_array = array(
"05.02.2020"=>2,
"06.02.2020"=>2,
"07.02.2020"=>'',
"08.02.2020"=>'',
"09.02.2020"=>'',
"10.02.2020"=>'',
"11.02.2020"=>'',
"12.02.2020"=>''
);
```

and if we need to get month this array will be

```
$month_array = array(
"01.02.2020"=>'',
"02.02.2020"=>2,
"03.02.2020"=>'',
"04.02.2020"=>'',
"05.02.2020"=>2,
"06.02.2020"=>2,
...
"29.02.2020"=>'');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check `array_key_exists` in `$view` array for your month or week array.

Here I share for the last 7 day's value.

```
<?php
$view = array("31.01.2020"=>2,"12.03.2020"=>2,"09.03.2020"=>2,"07.03.2020"=>2);

$week_array = array();

for($i=7;$i>0;$i--){
$week_array[date('d.m.Y', strtotime('-'.$i.' days'))] = "";

}
foreach($week_array as $week_key=>$week_value){

    if(array_key_exists($week_key,$view)){
        $week_array[$week_key] =$view[$week_key];
    }
}
print_r($week_array); exit;
?>
```

**Output**

```
Array
(
    [07.03.2020] => 2
    [08.03.2020] => 
    [09.03.2020] => 2
    [10.03.2020] => 
    [11.03.2020] => 
    [12.03.2020] => 2
    [13.03.2020] => 
)
```

Same you can do for last month or any records you want.

Hope this help to you.